# Ciclo anidado para validar array bidimensional

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, array-bidimensional

Tengo que validar que los valores de un array bi-dimensional sean consecutivos. Hice dos ciclos anidados para comparar cada elemento con un contador, pero cuando ejecuto la función me devuelve false cualquiera sea el caso y no puedo ver por qué.

Por ejemplo, el siguiente array me debería devolver `true`:

```
x = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];
```

Y el siguiente me debería devolver `false`:

```
x = [
    [2, 1, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];
```

El código que tengo hasta el momento:

```
var x = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];

function chequear() {
    var contador = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < x.length; j++){
            if (x[i][j] == contador++) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}

chequear();
```

Comment: ¿cuál es el resultado que buscas obtener al comparar?

Comment: que cuando 

 x = [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]
    ]; me devuelva true. Si  x = [
        [2, 1, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]
    ]; me devuelva false

Comment: No entiendo la comparativa que tratas de hacer, ¿cuando sean de la misma longitud, cuando sean consecutivos?....

Comment: cuando sean consecutivos. Necesito validar que x tenga exactamente esos valores en ese orden.

Comment: Lo más sencillos es que incluyeras varios ejemplos de datos de entrada y la salida esperada de cada ejemplo.

Comment: @MaguiiTa, he añadido tus comentarios a la pregunta en mi edición. Pero debes saber que cuando quieras añadir más cosas para hacer tu pregunta más clara, puedes hacerlo clicando el enlace de _editar_ situado bajo a tu pregunta, en vez de situar las aclaraciones en los comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos cosas que debes tener en cuenta con tu código:

1 - Una vez que haces un return dentro de los ciclos, ya no seguirás chequeando los siguientes valores. Dentro del segundo ciclo tienes una condición, si el primer valor del array coincide con `contador` devuelves `true`, si no coincide, devuelves `false`, pero que devuelva `true` no quiere decir que hayas chequeado si todo el array cumple la condición, solo significa que el primer valor coincide con tu chequeo. Aquí te sitúo tu mismo código con un `console.log` antes del chequeo para que notes cuántas veces se ejecuta dicho `console.log`:

```js
var x = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

function chequear() {
  var contador = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
      console.log('chequeando el valor ' + x[i][j]);
      if (x[i][j] == contador++) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
}
chequear();
```

2 - Lo segundo que debes tener en cuenta es que el operador `++` actúa diferente dependiendo de en qué lugar lo sitúes con respecto al operando. Si lo sitúas después del operado, primero retornará el valor de este y después lo incrementará en `1`, si lo sitúas antes, primero lo incrementará en `1` y después retornará el valor final incrementado. Observa el siguiente snippet para que entiendas cómo funciona cada uno:

```js
var contador = 0;

console.log( contador++ );
console.log( ++contador );
```

Entenderás entonces por qué te devuelve `false`, el valor de la variable `contador` es `0` al inicio, en tu chequeo, al tener el operador `++` después, chequearás la primera vez si `1` es igual a `0`, la segunda vez si `2` es igual a `1` y así consecutivamente. Tu validación nunca será verdadera.

Por lo tanto, teniendo en cuenta estas observaciones, aquí te dejo una variación de tu código. Por defecto sitúo un `return` con valor `true` al final de la función, si los ciclos corren completamente y terminan, quiere decir que los valores del array pasan la condición. Pero hay una condición en el segundo ciclo, usando el operador `++` antes del operando, que chequea si algún valor es diferente, y si lo es, retorna `false`. Puedes comprobar la función en el siguiente snippet usando dos arrays, el primero es válido y el segundo no:

```js
var x = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

var y = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [8, 7, 9]
];

function chequear(array) {
  var contador = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      if (array[i][j] !== ++contador) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log( chequear(x) );
console.log( chequear(y) );
```

Comment: muchas gracias! me quedo super clara la explicacion :)

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido @MaguiiTa, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Uno de los errores es que en los dos `for` estás usando `x.length` como límite del número de iteraciones. En el segundo deberías usar algo como `x[0].length` para que itere por el número de elementos del array interior.

Al usar `x.length` se obtiene el número filas. Estrictamente es el número de elementos del array del primer nivel/dimensión ó exterior.
Al usar algo como `x[0].length` se obtiene el número de columnas. Estrictamente es el número de elementos del primer array que es miembro del array de primer nivel o de la segunda dimension ó interior.

Cuando se trata de una matriz cuadrada (mismo número de filas y de columnas), como es este caso, puedes usar el ejemplo dado, pero si se tratara de un "[jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array)" (los elementos de los arrays interiores no son del mismo tamaño, o no se tiene certeza de que los sean) deberías usar `x[i].length`. Estrictamente, un array bi-dimensional es un tipo de "jagged array".

A continuación el código de la pregunta con unas ligeras modificaciones, 1) el cambio sugerido arriba, 2) el contador cuenta el número de elementos del array bidimensional

```js
var x = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

function chequear() {
  var contador = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < x[0].length; j++) {
    contador++
    }
  }
  return contador
}
console.info(chequear());
```

El otro problema del código es la lógica de lo que quieres hacer con cada elemento del array, pero con eso no te podremos ayudar mientras no lo describas claramente.

Comment: @MaguiiTa Esta muy bien que pidas clarificación de la repuesta, por otro lado, la clarificación de lo que estás buscando la deberías hacer editando la pregunta.

Comment: ah perdon, soy nueva por aqui :)

Comment: @MaguiiTa No hay problema, encantado de poder orientarte.